# How to get latin extended characters sort properly on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Latin extended characters do not sort properly on Parse.com (screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sc9uozrav9fsslo/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-04%20at%2012.22.54%20AM.png).
This is common behaviour for a database. With MySQL this problem is solved with Collation.
Anyone else had this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  You can try opening a Bug Report via the Bug Tool here:  https://parse.com/help